# English translation of the temple chants in Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom?

Tags: translation, indiana-jones, indiana-jones-and-temple-of-doom

Does anyone know the English translation of the temple chants in Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom? Like what they're singing and what Mola Ram is saying? Been wondering this for a long long time.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Well, I am not quite sure about the background chants (something in Sanskrit language) but Mola Ram ([Amrish Puri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amrish_Puri)) prays to [Kali Maa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali) (considered as goddess of power) in the ["Temple of Doom's heart removal scene"](https://youtu.be/iiE5mE0ZorA?t=88) as follows:

- Boy (to be sacrificed)

  > "Agar koi hai toh mujhe bachao"  = "If somebody's there, then save me !"
  >   "Koi mujhe, koi mujhe bachao"  = "somebody, somebody save me !"
  >   (*starts chanting..*)
  >   "Om namah shivay"       = "I devote myself to [Shiv*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva)" (Hindu god of destruction)
- Mola Ram

  > "bali chadhogay"    = "(you) will be sacrificed"
  >   "bali mangti kali maa"  = "mother kali wants offering/sacrifice"
  >   "mukti degi kalli maa"  = "mother kali will give salvation"
  >   "kali maa"       = "Mother kali" 
  >   "kali maa shakti de"  = "Mother kali give (me) power"
  >   "bali chadhau tere aage"= " (I) offer sacrifice before you"
  >   "swikar karo"       = "(please) accept"
  >   (*removes heart*....*boy screams*, *girl screams*)
  >   "ab iski jaan meri muthi main hai" = "now his life is in my hands" (*shows Myogenic contraction of heart to crowd*) 
  >   "bali chadhado"    = "do the sacrifice" (sacrifice him)
  >   (*boy dies chanting..*)

*Kali is an incarnation of Parvati, who is the wife of Shiv.

source: knows Hindi.

Comment: Thank you! You have no idea how long I've been pondering this. Twenty-six years to be exact. Much thanks. And , I'm kinda new to this site, so I might have accidentally gave your comment negative feedback. I hit the down button. Idk what that means but I assume its negative feedback. I went to hit the up button, and it said I have already left feedback. So sorry I didn't mean to do that. Positive positive positive feedback lol

Comment: I think I marked it as the right answer. Is it the checkmark ✔ ? I clicked it and it turned green. Hopefully, I can find out what they're singing too. If I find that out, I'll be complete LoL.

Comment: yeah, you marked it right. The singing is in Sanskrit language but the thing that makes it difficult to understand is the "opera-like" singing. Maybe someday someone will post the translation.

Comment: Hope so. Hint..., Hint..., to any readers out there. LoL

Answer (score 2):

Source IMDB:

> During the sacrifice, Mola Ram chants in Hindi, imploring "*Kali Ma Shakti de*," asking for the "**Spiritual power of Mother [*Kali*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali)** (*Goddess in Hindu Mythology*)."
>
> Mola Ram's chantings of "**Maaro maaro sooar ko, chamdi nocho pee lo khoon**" literally translated from Hindi is "**Kill, Kill the pig, flay his skin, drink his blood**".
>
> "**Aum Namah Shivaya**" ("adoration to Lord Shiva"). It is chanted to help protect one's soul during times of peril

Comment: That's when Mola Ram is trying to rip out Indy's heart on the cut rope bridge. ...